# Encrypted jdbc connection to db2 on mainframe

Tags: java, encryption, jdbc, db2, mainframe

I am connecting to a DB2 Server running on mainframe via JDBC.
I have a requirement to establish an encrypted connection! I need to achieve encrypted connection or encryption of data over network. 
Can you please help me how I can achieve the same!

I have established encrypted connection with Oracle server running on linux as shown in the link [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14268/asojbdc.htm#i1006379)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [securityMechanism 13](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvjcsen.html) (ENCRYPTED_USER_PASSWORD_AND_DATA_SECURITY) in the db2 jdbc driver. E.g. using DB2SimpleDataSource:

```
import com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource;
...

DB2SimpleDataSource ds = new DB2SimpleDataSource(); 
ds.setDriverType(4);      
ds.setDatabaseName("<db name>");
ds.setServerName("<server name>");  
ds.setPortNumber(<port>); 
ds.setUser("<user>");      
ds.setPassword("<password>");

// Set security mechanism to User ID and encrypted password
ds.setSecurityMechanism(DB2BaseDataSource.ENCRYPTED_USER_PASSWORD_AND_DATA_SECURITY);
ds.setEncryptionAlgorithm(2);       // Request AES encryption
```

**For this to work, you need to patch your JVM with the unrestricted policy file for JCE.**

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ebbe's answer you can also use SSL/TLS for your jdbc-connection - although this requires some amount of work on the server-side. In particular your systems-people have to setup AT-TLS for your mainframe's TCP-stack which is a bit of work if it's not already implemented for some application. Then you have to define a policy for DB2's jdbc-port to use SSL/TLS.

Finally on the client side you just have to set a property on your jdbc-connection to enable TLS:

```
java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
props.put( "user", user );
props.put( "password", pass );
props.put( "sslConnection", "true" );
java.sql.Connection con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

Detailed instructions can be found in [this redpaper](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/redp4799.html?Open).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already posted, there is a very simple solution I seldom see mentioned - switch your connection from IPv4 to IPv6. Among its many other attributes, IPv6 includes built-in encryption on any session, so merely altering your network address from an IPv4 address to an IPv6 address might be all that's needed. There's some network and system configuration to do on the mainframe for this, but once setup, you can guarantee that all JDBC network connections are by default encrypted.

Answer (score -2):

Step 1: Make a non-encrypted connection to DB2 via JDBC.  Get it working and test it thoroughly.

Step 2: Get an encrypted simple data transfer to the mainframe working, even if it is only to pass text messages like "Hello World!"  Get it working and test it thoroughly.

Step 3: Merge the two to achieve the full connection:

```
JDBC -> Encryption -> Transfer -> Decryption -> DB2
```

Doing it in stages helps you isolate any problems.  In step 2 you will need to avoid using system defaults to encrypt or decrypt, explicitly specify everything on both sides.  If things don't match exactly, byte-for-byte, then crypto is designed to fail.  Also beware of nit-picky things like character encoding and byte order.  For example, does your mainframe use EBCDIC, ASCII/ANSI or Unicode?  Common assumptions in the PC world do not always carry over to mainframes.

Comment: I don't think "roll your own" is particularly helpful when communicating with a complex server-system that already offers various methods of encryption out of the box. And I don't htink this could possibly work - how would you encrypt the jdbc-login? Build some sort of proxy-server before the database?

Comment: Where is the "roll your own"?  I am assuming that compatible encryption software is available on both systems and similarly that compatible intercommunications software is available on both systems.  If built-in encrypted communications are already available then why is the question being asked?

Comment: "why is the question being asked" - because the OP doesn't know how to activate the ecnryption? And for the answer to be of any use you should perhaps elaborate on item 3: We are talking about wrapping a TCP-based communications-protocol with an encryption-layer, not about some filetransfer. How would you intercept the communication on the client, how on the server-side?